# .net core list removeall() method is strange

Tags: c#, list

It seems very simple, but this error happens.

```
        IList<string> list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("001");
        list.Add("002");
        list.Add("003");
        list.Add("004");

        list.ToList().RemoveAll(s => s == "002");
        return list.Count.ToString();
```

The list Count should be 3, but it will still be 4. Is a bug in RemoveAll() method? If using List rathan than IList declaration, it works well.

**Edit**
1. If not using ToList() method, there is no RemoveAll() method to call.

2. How can I avoid this situation to use IList as a argument, list firstly is a reference type. Should I not use IList as a declaration totally? We have used IList everythere in our project.

   ```
   public string List()
   {
       IList<string> list = new List<string>();
       list.Add("001");
       list.Add("002");
       list.Add("003");
       list.Add("004");

       Remove(list);
       return list.Count.ToString();
   }

   private void Remove(IList<string> list)
   {
       list.ToList().RemoveAll(a => a == "002");
   }
   ```
3. If there is a new method to support, it will be better. Thanks everyone here.

Comment: " If not using ToList() method, there is no RemoveAll() method to call." because you're not declaring it as a List of string but an IList of string which doesn't contain this method, change the type you declare (on the left of list) to the type you actually use (on the right with new)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're using `ToList` you actually create a shallow copy of the list, which then you apply the `RemoveAll` on the new list, thus, the original list doesn't been affected.

If you only looking for the **count** of none-"002" items, then simple count will suffice

```
list.Count - list.Count(i => i == "002");
```

Otherwise if you actually want to remove those items from the original list, then you will need to solve it the old fashion way, using for loop.

Anyway, if `IList` is not that important, you can save the list as `List` and not `IList`, and use `RemoveAll` method.

Answer (score 1):

`ToList()` returns a shallow copy of the original `list` (ie, it's a new instance and modifications made to it will not be reflected back in `list`).

Since you need to use the `RemoveAll` method, I recommend storing the variable as `List` instead of [`IList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist?view=netcore-3.0#methods):

```cs
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("001");
list.Add("002");
list.Add("003");
list.Add("004");
list.RemoveAll(s => s == "002");

Console.WriteLine(list.Count()); // 3
```

You can also achieve the same thing using LINQ operators:

```cs
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("001");
list.Add("002");
list.Add("003");
list.Add("004");
list = list.Where(s => s != "002").ToList();

Console.WriteLine(list.Count());
```

More succinctly:

```cs
List<string> list = new List<string>(new[] {
    "001",
    "002",
    "003",
    "004"
});

// or
//List<string> list = new[] {
//  "001",
//  "002",
//  "003",
//  "004"
//}.ToList();

Console.WriteLine(list.Count(s => s != "002")); // 3
```